# Sorting time complexities

Tags: algorithm, complexity-theory

Given the following complexities list :

```
n^(log log(n) )  ;2^n  ;3^n  ;n! ;  n^3  ;1/n  ;(n+1)!  ;  4^log(n)   ;n^2  

n^log(n)   ;log(n!)  ;nln(n)  ;  log(2^n )=nlog2 ;(log(2) )^n  ;5n^2+6  ;  n^log(n!)
```

I need to sort them by classes .

I sorted part of them by the following order , but I'm still missing a few :

```
(n+1)!  
n!
3^n
2^n
(3/2)^n
(log(n))^log(n) =n^log(log(n) ) 
n^3
n^2 = 4*log(n) = 4^log(n) 
5n^2+6 = Θ(n^2 )
log(n!) = Θ(n*log(n))
nlog(2) = log(2^n )
```

Where do I need to put the rest :

```
n^log(n)  ;  n*ln(n) ; (log(2))^n ; n^[log(n!)] ; 1/n ;
```

?

And , how can I divide them into common classes ?

I'd appreciate any help

Regards

Comment: Off-topic: this should probably be on http://cs.stackexchange.com.

Comment: I cannot tell you how to answer this as a homework question.  That may depend on what your instructor wants.  However, though computer science regrettably frequently fails to recognize it, n! is of infinite order and log(n) is of zeroth order.  L'Hospital's rule governs.  (I really don't think that comment this will help you on your homework, though, because the way the question is phrased suggests that your instructor disagrees with the comment's premise.)

Comment: @thb, there are many complexities higher than `n!` and many lower than `log(n)`. Calling them infinite and zeroth order doesn't make sense to me. Do you have any references?

Comment: Why off-topic ? time complexity is a very important element in Complexity , is it not ?

Comment: @Shahbaz: No reference, sorry.  Justification:  a function *f(z)* has order *m* if *f(z)/z^(m-epsilon)* diverges and *f(z)/z^(m+epsilon)* converges for large *z.*  Except in the software world, the order of a function is a number, not a discussion.  Hence, *O(log(n))* is only an obscure way to say *O(1).*  And the reality of software profiling in fact reflects this, though computer science tends to deny it.  Consider the performance of a self-balancing binary tree with n = 1 billion elements to see what I mean.  But, like Quixote, I tilt at windmills in this.  Comp. sci. disputes the math.

Answer (score 0):

You have done well so far. Since this is a homework, I won't give an exact answer, but only hints about the ones you are missing:

- `n^log(n)`: this grows faster than `(log(n))^(log(n))`, but is not as fast as exponentials. You can confirm this by comparing `log`s of these three expressions together.
- `n*ln(n)`: `ln(n)` is `ln(10)log(n)`. In general, log a in base c, is log a in base b multiplied by log b in base c.
- `(log(2))^n`: This is an exponential with base `log(2)` which is ~ 0.3. This is almost (3.333^-n) which exponentially decreases.
- `n^[log(n!)]`: `log(n!)` is `O(nlog(n))`. This means `n^(log(n!))` is `O(n^n * n^log(n))`
- `1/n`: This is `n^(-1)` which decreases slowly by value.

Comment: I've answered my question , would greatly appreciate if you could give me a feedback ...:)

Answer (score 0):

My final answer :

```
n^log(n!) 
(n+1)!  
n!
3^n
2^n
(3/2)^n
n^log(n) 
(log(n) )^log(n) =n^log(log(n) ) 
n^3
n^2=4 log(n)=4^log(n)
5n^2+6=Θ(n^2 )
log(n!)=Θ(nlog(n))
n⋅ln(n)
nlog(2)=log(2^n )
(log(2))^n≈(0.3)^n
1/n=n^(-1)
```

What do you think  ?

Comment: `4^(log(n))` is `n^(log(4))` which would be `n^2` if your log is base 2, but how did you get `4*log(n)` equal to those?! Also, if your log is base 2, then `log(2)` would be 1, so `log(2)^n` would be simply 1.